# Retrieving additional dimensions from NetCDF through GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, netcdf

I am working with NetCDFs through the NetCDF extension for GeoServer.
I have additional dimensions within the NetCDF that I can see through ncdump and ToolsUI, but I can't figure out how to retrieve that data.
The data does not have lat/lon associations, it is simply an array of floating-point numbers.

How could I retrieve this NetCDF data through GeoServer?

Comment: if your data has no geographic component, how do you expect GeoServer to display it for you?

Comment: The time is not geographic, yet that is retrievable.  I was hoping something similar for the other fields, although time may be a special case.

Comment: Can you spin up a THREDDS server for it?